# Closing all open command prompt leads to error in forked process in testNG

Tags: selenium, testing, testng, appium

I am using testNG for mobile automation and I want to close multiple command prompts(appium servers) which i launched. For this, I am using the below code

```
@AfterSuite
    public void closeCommandPrompts() throws IOException, InterruptedException{
    System.out.println("After suite");
    Thread.sleep(8000);
    Runtime.getRuntime().exec("taskkill /F /IM node.exe");
    System.out.println("closed node.exe");
    Runtime.getRuntime().exec("taskkill /F /IM cmd.exe");
```

The last line if I commnet it out works fine, however if they are not commented it gives an error in the forked process.

I guess testNG is internally using command prompt which i am trying to close when iam using taskkilll in @aftersuite.

Please help me in getting some work around.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use following code :

```
     CommandLine command = new CommandLine("cmd");
      command.addArgument("/c");
      command.addArgument("taskkill");
      command.addArgument("/F");
      command.addArgument("/IM");
      command.addArgument("node.exe");

      DefaultExecuteResultHandler resultHandler = new DefaultExecuteResultHandler();
      DefaultExecutor executor = new DefaultExecutor();
      executor.setExitValue(1);
      try {
            executor.execute(command, resultHandler);
            System.out.println("Stopped appium node ! ");
      } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println("FAIL => Unable to stop appium server "+e.getMessage());
            e.printStackTrace();
      }
```

Comment: thanks @Shekhar, the code is successfully terminating the node.exe , but its not closing the command prompt (on which appium is running).

Comment: @Rajitsrajan oh ! then write a finally block after catch block : `finally {
     try {
              Runtime.getRuntime().exec("taskkill /f /im cmd.exe") ;
          } catch (Exception e) {
              e.printStackTrace();  
          }
  }`

Comment: When I am executing it...it gives me error in forked process. I guess testng was internally using command prompt.Hence when i run Runtime.getRuntime().exec("taskkill /f /im cmd.exe") ; - it gives error.


However this line only closes the node and not command prompt. I want to close the command prompt as well.

Comment: I would like to suggest you here to run your java program using platform-specific script (e.g. bat file for windows & shell script for UNIX) that is responsible for closing the prompt

Comment: @Rajitsrajan how are you running your framework/project ?

Comment: Since I am using TestNG to run my test cases, so at any phase I cant call 

 Runtime.getRuntime().exec("taskkill /F /IM cmd.exe");

as this would yield in error in forked process. Any suggestions

Comment: Okay no issues.. Create a .bat file and write your command into .bat file. Run this .bat file. cmd prompt will automatically get closed at the end.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/112369/discussion-between-shekhar-swami-and-rajit-s-rajan).